# How do I Dual boot Mac OS(X) and Kubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, kde, mac

I have a mac and I need to dual boot Kubuntu 16.10 and Mac OSX.

How can I do this? Do I have to delete all my data from OSX?